# AngularJS - передача данных в отдельные модули

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем привет! Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста - какую статью [ или статьи (: ] курить для полного понимания. Или на какие разделы обратить внимание в документации. Суть вопроса в передаче данных между модулями в AngularJS.

если более подробно:

Делаю свое первое тестовое приложение в виде магазина, нужно на нем реализовать авторизацию. Само приложение разбито на несколько отдельных компонентов, каждый со своим контроллером. Т.е. идет например страница с товаром - все это находится в отдельной вьюшке, со своим отдельным контроллером - в виде компонента.

Нужно сделать так , чтобы авторизовавшийся пользователь был виден во всех вьюшках, к примеру кликает на товар - он добавляется в корзину, переходит в корзину - видит список товаров который накликал, нажимает оплатить - и с соотстветсвенного поля фейкогового объекта списывается сумма покупки.

Думал реализовать все это через глобальный контроллер, к основному модулю, который бы к примеру прописывался в body, но идея почему то не кажется хорошей :)

Comment: [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: А почему так? Я всегда представлял себе, что каждое приложение реализует отдельный модуль, а все остальное - авторизация, формы, корзина и пр. - отдельные контроллеры, а данными, например, токеном авторизации - обмениваются через rootScope.